# FlexBox every div same size + align-items = flex-start

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create something like this:

[image]

At the moment I have created this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.article {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.productImg {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="article">
    <img class="productImg" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/3847/jetty-landing-stage-sea-sky.jpeg" />
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <img class="productImg" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/3847/jetty-landing-stage-sea-sky.jpeg" />
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <img class="productImg" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/3847/jetty-landing-stage-sea-sky.jpeg" />
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <img class="productImg" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/3847/jetty-landing-stage-sea-sky.jpeg" />
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <img class="productImg" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/3847/jetty-landing-stage-sea-sky.jpeg" />
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <img class="productImg" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/3847/jetty-landing-stage-sea-sky.jpeg" />
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <img class="productImg" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/3847/jetty-landing-stage-sea-sky.jpeg" />
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <img class="productImg" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/3847/jetty-landing-stage-sea-sky.jpeg" />
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <img class="productImg" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/3847/jetty-landing-stage-sea-sky.jpeg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything works well, but the last `.article` is sometimes to big. The size should be the same as the `.article` above him. How can I do this? 
I've tried it with max- and min-width, but this didn't worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
.article {
  max-width: calc(50% - 40px);
}
```

If u cant use `calc()`, change `margin` and `padding` size to procentage

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I combine it with some `media-queries` and then it should be perfect. Thanks alot.